# Why usort doesn't work inside of function?

Tags: php, usort

Here is the code - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ac3b31af0ce4d348f91957b314a8fa089cc8e779
It works only if 95 string is uncommented.

I spent half a day to make code from here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192827/2653694 - to work. But for some reasons usort doesn't work inside of function. Why?..

Relevant part of code:

```
function fs($array){

    usort($array, 'sortByOrder');

};

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['order_inside_level'] - $b['order_inside_level'];
};

fs($array);
// usort($array, 'sortByOrder'); // If to uncomment this string then array is ordered by 'order_inside_level'

var_dump($array);
```

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the code directly in your question.

Comment: In addition to @Felix Kling's comment, What's it returning?

Comment: As I see it, you are not using usort correctly. On [php.net page of usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), you have to return 3 cases with your callback function: -1, 0 or 1.

Comment: @machineaddict, no, it's correct. It's working without any functions. Try to uncomment string.

Comment: @dwhite.me, please, look at sandbox. It should return the same array which keys are sorted by order_inside_level (1,2,...).

Comment: Pass the array by reference and it will work. `function fs(&$array){...}`

Comment: You have removed `&` symbol. Why?

Comment: @John Smith: You didn't understand me. Anyway, you can also use anonymous functions as callbacks. I have never had your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass an array to a function, a **copy** of the array is created and passed. The same happens when you *assign* an array to another variable.

I.e, you are sorting the copy, not the original array.

You can define that the array should be passed by reference with:

```
function fs(&$array){

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing your array to function by value, not reference, therefore your `usort()` call is NOT sorting the source array but its copy. Either pass your array by reference ([see docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)):

```
function fs(&$array) {
   usort($array, 'sortByOrder');
}
```

or use `global $array;` and drop passing it as function argument (bad idea)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to pass the array by reference:

```
function fs(&$array){
    usort($array, 'sortByOrder');
};
```